# Setting Entry Behaviors using Style attribute

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have defined my style as such:

```
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Entry" x:Key="IntegralEntryBehavior">
            <Setter Property="Behaviors" Value="valid:EntryIntegerValidationBehavior"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

And multiple similar Entries:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    <Entry Style="{StaticResource IntegralEntryBehavior}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

If I define Entry behavior like this, I get an error, that `Entry.Behaviors property is readonly`, but it's possible to define behavior without using `Style` attribute inside Entry as such:

```
<Entry.Behaviors>
    <valid:EntryIntegerValidationBehavior/>
</Entry.Behaviors>
```

What is the difference between these approaches and why does only the second one work? Is it possible to modify the first approach to make it work? I'm looking for a shorter way to define this behavior for each entry than the second option.

Comment: you can check this out http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=249

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can checkout the example here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating#consuming-a-xamarinforms-behavior-with-a-style

Basically, add an attached property to your behavior and then set the style setter's property to that attached property. The attached property handles adding itself to the `Entry` that you attach it to.

```
public class EntryIntegerValidationBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
  public static readonly BindableProperty AttachBehaviorProperty =
    BindableProperty.CreateAttached ("AttachBehavior", typeof(bool), typeof(EntryIntegerValidationBehavior), false, propertyChanged: OnAttachBehaviorChanged);

  public static bool GetAttachBehavior (BindableObject view)
  {
    return (bool)view.GetValue (AttachBehaviorProperty);
  }

  public static void SetAttachBehavior (BindableObject view, bool value)
  {
    view.SetValue (AttachBehaviorProperty, value);
  }

  static void OnAttachBehaviorChanged (BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var entry = view as Entry;
    if (entry == null) {
        return;
    }

    bool attachBehavior = (bool)newValue;
    if (attachBehavior) {
        entry.Behaviors.Add (new EntryIntegerValidationBehavior ());
    } else {
        var toRemove = entry.Behaviors.FirstOrDefault (b => b is EntryIntegerValidationBehavior);
        if (toRemove != null) {
            entry.Behaviors.Remove (toRemove);
        }
    }
  }

  // Actual behavior code here

}
```

Finally edit your style to look like this:

```
    <Style TargetType="Entry" x:Key="IntegralEntryBehavior">
        <Setter Property="valid:EntryIntegerValidationBehavior.AttachBehavior" Value="true"/>
    </Style>
```

Comment: What if to pass any additional value? create another attachable property?

Comment: @MayurPaghdal You could create a new attached property or assign a more complex object to your attached property that can hold more than just a boolean.